# Segue from the view controller embedded in a container view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode-storyboard

My application has a `UIViewController` which is embedded in a `UINavigationController`. The `UIViewController` has a container view inside it. I connect this container view to a `UITableViewController` thereby embedding it in the container view. It's fine until now.

Now when I connect this `UITableViewController` to a new `UIViewController` using the push segue (we are still in the navigation view) in the storyboard, the size of the new `UIViewController` scene becomes same as that of the container view. I guess this is expected but is there some way not to make this happen. I want the remaining scenes to be in the normal size. Also, its working pretty fine and as expected when running in the simulator. The problem with the size is only pertained to the storyboard.

Just explaining my controller - view hierarchy here:

```
UINavigationController 
  -> UIViewController ( Initial View Controller )
    -> Container View 
      -> UITableViewController ( Embed Segue ) 
        -> UIViewController ( Push Segue )
```

Is there any way so that the last `UIViewController` and the remaining connected controller scenes are of normal sizes in the storyboard?

Comment: So the problem is only when viewing the storyboard? The view controller has a "simulated metrics" size option (by default it's inferred). Have you tried changing that?

Comment: I'm having the opposite problem. I want my segue'd view to fit the size of a container it's in!

Answer (score 4):

Here is one solution: Create a manual segue from your Initial View Controller to the desired destination. This will prevent the storyboard from getting confused and giving the destination the wrong size (and other inferred metrics). Unfortunately, because it is a manual view controller, you will have to perform the segue in code from your embedded view controller by doing something like this:

```
[self.parentViewController.parentViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

**As of Xcode 7 (I'm not sure if this applies to previous versions):**

1. Select the view controller that is embedded inside your container view.
2. In the `Attributes Selector`, there are five drop downs at the top under `Simulated Metrics`.

   - Set `Size` to `Master`
   - Set `Status Bar` to `Default`
   - Set `Top Bar` to `Translucent Navigation Bar`
3. Now drag a `UINavigationItem` onto your view controller.

This will give you the correctly sized view controller and a navigation bar to edit.